# react error 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/reset">
            <PasswordReset />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}
```

Hi, I get an error. I am running the react application for the first time.
'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'
I tried typing Routers instead of Switch, it was not accepted.
what can I do? thanks.

Comment: What version of react-router do you have? If you have v6 installed, you need to [upgrade your code](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update '**react-router-dom**' to *v6* by 'npm -i --save react-router-dom@6'.
Next, *.. router v6* have new syntax, you should using **Routes** instead of **Switch**. Also, **Routes** consist of **Route's**, and use **element** instead of **component**, example:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path='/'>
    <SomeComponent />
  </Route>
  
     or

  <Route path='/' element={<SomeComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: npm install react-router-dom@5 solve my problem thanks